# Unable to match python flask api input to mysql query value

Tags: python, mysql, select, match

I have a simple python/flask api that I am unable to match an input in the api to mysql select results:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute('SELECT code FROM users')
codes = mycursor.fetchall()
```

codes prints like so '[('0000',), ('0001',), ('0003',)]'

Here is the api route and lookup code:

```
# API route for when a code is passed
@app.route('/api/v1/codes', methods=['GET'])
def checkcode():
    # Check if a code was provided as part of the URL.
    # If code is provided, assign it to a variable.
    # If no code is provided, display an error in the browser.
    if 'id' in request.args:
        code = request.args['id']
        print(id)
    else:
        return "Error: No id field provided. Please specify an id."

    # Check if code matches
    if code in codes:
        #unlock(),
        pushMessage("Message from PiAPI", "Building Door Unlocked.")
    else:
        wrong = 'Wrong Code was sent ' + (code)
        pushMessage('Message from PiAPI', wrong)
```

I've tried getting the code to match in every way I can conceive like so:

```
code = "('" + request.args['id'] + "',)"
code = "'" + request.args['id'] + "',"
code = "'" + request.args['id'] + "'"
```

Nothing has matched so far so even though it looks correct it and gets sent correctly in the else: pushmessage. In the api I'm entering 0000 (/api/v1/codes?id=0000)

I'm 42 and brand new to coding so please forgive any stupidity. :)

Comment: Flatten your code list like this: `codes = [record[0] for record in codes]`, and the rest of the route should work as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing this answer of off @mechanical_meat code in the comment above.

Currently you have

```
codes = [('0000',), ('0001',), ('0003',)]
```

which is a list with tuples inside it.

Thus what you end up comparing when id=0000

```
if 0000 == ('0000',):
```

Which as you have pointed out is always false

```
codes = [record[0] for record in codes]
```

will change it to look like this:

```
codes = ['0000', '0001', '0003']
```

i.e flatten it